# Why input image gets flipped after convolution operation?

Tags: numpy, convolution

[image]I am trying to create the convolution operation from scratch in order to understand what goes under the hood. When I visualise the activation after convolution layer the image is flipped. Just wanted to ask if I am doing correct or not. I experimented it with one image which is attached below. I am also attaching Activations from convolution layer across 3 channels. [image]

Size of input image  = (64, 64, 3)
Size of Activation after convolution layer = (33, 33, 3)

The image represents '5' as a sign.

```
def zero_pad(self, X, pad):
    """
    Set padding to the image X.

    Pads with zeros all images of the dataset X.
    Zeros are added around the border of an image.

    Parameters:
    X -- Image -- numpy array of shape (m, n_H, n_W, n_C)
    pad -- padding amount -- int

    Returns:
    X_pad -- Image padded with zeros around width and height. -- numpy array of shape (m, n_H + 2*pad, n_W + 2*pad, n_C)

    """
    X_pad = np.pad(X, ((0, 0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad), (0, 0)), 'constant')
    return X_pad

def convolve(self, image_slice, W, b):
    """
    Apply a filter defined by W on a single slice of an image.

    Parameters:
    image_slice -- slice of input data -- numpy array of shape (f, f, n_C_prev)
    W -- Weight parameters contained in a window - numpy array of shape (f, f, n_C_prev)
    b -- Bias parameters contained in a window - numpy array of shape (1, 1, 1)

    Returns:
    Z -- a scalar value, result of convolving the sliding window (W, b) on image_slice

    """
    s = np.multiply(image_slice, W)
    z = np.sum(s)
    Z = z + float(b)
    return Z

def get_corners(self, height, width, filter_size, stride):
    """
    Get corners of the image relative to stride.

    Parameters:
    height -- height of an image -- int
    width -- width of an image -- int
    filter_size -- size of filter -- int
    stride -- amount by which the filter shifts -- int

    Returns:
    vert_start -- a scalar value, upper left corner of the box.
    vert_end -- a scalar value, upper right corner of the box.
    horiz_start -- a scalar value, lower left corner of the box.
    horiz_end -- a scalar value, lower right corner of the box.

    """
    vert_start = height * stride
    vert_end = vert_start + filter_size
    horiz_start = width * stride
    horiz_end = horiz_start + filter_size
    return vert_start, vert_end, horiz_start, horiz_end

def forward(self, A_prev):
    """
    Forward proporgation for convolution.

    This takes activations from previous layer and then convolve it
    with a filter defined by W with bias b.

    Parameters:
    A_prev -- output activations of the previous layer, numpy array of shape (m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev)

    Returns:
    Z -- convolution output, numpy array of shape (m, n_H, n_W, n_C)

    """
    np.random.seed(self.seed)
    self.A_prev = A_prev
    filter_size, filter_size, n_C_prev, n_C = self.params[0].shape
    m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev = self.A_prev.shape
    Z = np.zeros((m, self.n_H, self.n_W, self.n_C))
    A_prev_pad = self.zero_pad(self.A_prev, self.pad)
    for i in range(m):
        a_prev_pad = A_prev_pad[i, :, :, :]
        for h in range(self.n_H):
            for w in range(self.n_W):
                for c in range(n_C):
                    vert_start, vert_end, horiz_start, horiz_end = self.get_corners(
                        h, w, self.filter_size, self.stride)
                    #if horiz_end <= a_prev_pad.shape[1] and vert_end <= a_prev_pad.shape[0]:
                    a_slice_prev = a_prev_pad[
                            vert_start:vert_end, horiz_start:horiz_end, :]
                    Z[i, h, w, c] = self.convolve(
                            a_slice_prev, self.params[0][:, :, :, c], self.params[1][:, :, :, c])
    self.Z_test = Z
    assert (Z.shape == (m, self.n_H, self.n_W, self.n_C))
    return Z
```

Comment: Can you provide the source for get_corners... I have a strong hunch that the problem has got to be there

Comment: @KylePena I have edited my question to add additional code.

Comment: The image is transposed rather than "upside down", meaning that the y and x axes have been interchanged.  Hate to be a bother but can you include your rendering code as well (what you used to produce the above image), and any other code you used?  I've read it a couple of times and I can't spot the bug.  I'm thinking now that matplotlib is doing it.

Comment: ok so I figure it out, it was quite a stupid error. I was doing plt.imshow(image, origin='lower') instead I did plt.imshow(image, origin='upper')

Comment: Cool. Guess I was right about marplotlib being the culprit.